# Why do we use sup rather than max when talking about the standard metric on real valued bounded functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the metric on the space of Real-valued bounded functions,

$$d(f,g) =\sup \{ |f(x) - g(x) | | x \in \left[ a, b \right] \}$$

I don't get why the supremum is used here. Wouldn't just maximum suffice?

---

Here is some background of what I do know. The sup is the least upper bound, and this may or may not exist inside our set. Consider for example the sequence given below:

$$ a_n = ( 1 + \frac{1}{n})^n,   n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Clearly $a_n< e$ for all values of $n$ but $e$ itself doesn't itself exist in the set $S=\{ a_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

In the case of the metric I originally took, it's that all points of the input are okay , so, could I use for max instead of a sup? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, who says the maximum of $|f-g|$ exists? COnsider for example $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $g=0$ and $f(x)=x$ if $x\in [0,1)$ and $f(1)=0$. Then, $\sup|f-g|=\sup|f|=1$, but $|f-g|=f$ doesn't have a maximum

Comment: The functions are bounded , right? so it must be that they can't shoot off to infinity @peek-a-boo

Comment: What is the difference between "$\max$" and $\sup$"?

Comment: even if things are bounded, the maximum need not exist

Comment: the max may not be attained. For example, $f(x)=x\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q^c}}(x)$ is bounded in $[0,1]$ and $d(f,0)=1$, but there is no $x\in[0,1]$ at which $f(f,0)=|f(x)-0|=f(x)$.

Comment: How is that possible? Could you give an example @peek-a-boo

Comment: The maximum is the supremum if it exists, meaning if the function racially reaches the maximum; but the "maximum" may instead be approached only asymptotically, as in the function $f(x)=1-\exp(-x), x\in\mathbb R$. "Supremum" covers such a situation.

Comment: I don't understand your notation , what is $x1_{\mathbb{Q}^c}(x)$ @OliverDiaz

Comment: See my edited first comment for a counterexample. (also Oliver Diaz's comment). Now, if you were talking about **continuous** functions on $[a,b]$, then that's a different story, because the extreme value theorem tells you the maximum exists (since $[a,b]$ is compact). In this case, the maximum equals the supremum. But again, this is a special case, so we should always use supremum because it always exists in $[0,\infty]$ (and in $[0,\infty)$ when dealing with bounded functions).

Comment: Oh right, I get it now, the sup can exist not only due to the interval we are taking over but also how you define the function over it @peek-a-boo.

Comment: @Buraian: For any function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $A\subset[a,b]$, $g=f\mathbb{1}_A$ is the function that equals to $f$ on $A$ and is $0$ otherwise.